# Calculating amount of t/r tickets for crews working in shifts 4 weeks out 2 weeks home

Tags: extremal-combinatorics

I want to calculate how many flight tickets I would need to buy if I have a total of 6 men working in three (3) teams two (2) at the time at a building site for 4 weeks in a row that is projected to take 20 weeks. This way I always have 4 men on site, with one team overlapping the other. I also would like for the calculation to be variable, i.e. changing the duration to 40 weeks and the crew size etc. So far my calculations in Excel have been very static and only work for a specific set of rules. Any help?

So far I have tested a calculation for a construction duration of 10 weeks. You always have two teams working out and one team home. You also know that you have at least two tickets (1 tour/retour) for each team member. For this exact situation I got it to a total of 24 tickets. You start by sending two teams awy (4 tickets). One team is working 4 weeks and the other is working 2 weeks. Then the 3rd team is sent in, and the 2 week team sent home and the next team is then working 4 weeks. This way you always have 4 tickets every time (2 leaving and 2 returning) This occurs 6 times in 10 weeks. 6 times 4 (the total amount of individuals traveling each time) is 24. This is correct and all. But what if I chnge the duration to 40 weeks and the crew size from 2 to 4 or 8?! Confuses me a lot! Any help would be greatly appreciated!
KR
Martin Andreas

Comment: I suggest that your company hire a mathematical consultant.

Comment: Yes that would probably solve it as well, but I was set the task as I'm an BATCM intern right now at this company, and I thought this site might help me reach the right method of calculating the amount of tickets.

Comment: I don't know what BATCM is. Do you expect this company will regularly set you this type of task? Do you want to work for a company where you can only do your job by soliciting free advice on the internet? Does the company want to have an employee who can only do his job by soliciting free advice on the internet?

Comment: If you get help for your company from the mathematical community here, will you suggest them to finance in one way or another said community, for example through starting grants for young scientists (or under any other similar form)?

Comment: Ok, I'm an intern as a BATCM (Bachelor of Architectural Technology & Construction Management). Usually these calculations are done for one specific task. This is where I thought it would make sense to do a spreadsheet in Excel where you could modify the calculation with certain variables. I looked on the internet for how to accomplish this specific task and found this forum/site and thought "this seems like a place to get answers". Can't answer for this company's financial plans. And sorry for asking. I thought it would be interesting for someone to find out who is in to math.I'll ask a friend

Comment: And no, I don't expect them to regularly set me these kind of tasks. To be honest, then it was my idea with doing a spreadsheet as I thought it would be easier than it has turned out to be. So this is - for now - put on hold from my point of view. Got other things to do.

Answer (score 1):

Try to look at one variable at a time. Notice that crew size doesn't really matter, it just scales the overall answer. So assume crew size is $1$. Similarly the duration each crew stays and overall time for the job can be seen to be essentially scaling the overall result (some constant addition might be there). Now, try to solve the problem if at any given time, you need $r$ teams on site, instead of just $2$.

Comment: Ok, thank you. I realize that focusing down on one variable at the time will make it easier for me to solve the equation, but I find it difficult to boil it down and simplify.